# Vertical scrolling boxes in horizontal scrolling row with smoothDivScroll?

Tags: jquery, ipad

I need to create a UI in which boxes lay out in a row, and the user can scroll the row to view one box at a time. Also some boxes are taller than others, in which case the user should be able to scroll that box vertically. This has to work with swipe gestures as well as the mouse. My HTML is like this:

```
<div class="player-content">
  <article id="slide1"><img src="img/session1/screen1.png" width="760" height="400" alt="screen 1"></article>
  <article id="slide2"><img src="img/session1/screen2.png" width="760" height="400" alt="screen 2"></article>
  <article id="slide3"><iframe width="760" height="400" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VRKcDAOILI4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></article>
  ...
</div>
```

With smoothDivScroll I can get the whole row of boxes scrolling great, using this JS:

```
$("div.player-content").smoothDivScroll({
  mousewheelScrolling: 'horizontal',
  hotSpotScrolling: false,
  touchScrolling: true
});
```

However if I attempt to make the  elements scroll vertically using this code, all the swipe gestures break:

```
$('div.player-content').find('article').smoothDivScroll( {
  mousewheelScrolling: 'vertical',
  hotSpotScrolling: false,
  touchScrolling: true
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to close this question, since I've abandoned smoothDivScroll for the swiper plugin, which does what I need:

http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/